# Chrome Extension Installation Issues (No Page Action Icon & Failure to Automatically Update)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After spending a week or so trying to resolve these issues, I am unable to find any solutions.

I have successfully published my extension on Chrome's Webstore. The extension depends on a native application, so I bundled everything together and am using the Windows Registry to install my extension. Everything seems to work, except for two issues...

Just to clarify, when I load the unpackaged extension or download the extension from the webstore manually, everything works perfectly.

(My extension is a page action)

1. After installing the extension using the registry, Chrome successfully prompts the user to install the extension. After installing the extension, when the user navigates to a page that uses the extension, the content scripts and background script all run perfectly. **However the page action icon does not appear. The user must access the page icon, so this is of vital importance.**
2. When I publish an update for the extension, **the user's browser does not update the extension version even after 24 hours**. I am not sure if this is a function of installing the extension through the registry, but everything I've checked suggests this would not be the case.

---

3. While not unique to me, some users experience the page action icon disappearing after extended use of the extension. I have found this issue on the message boards, and I was under the impression it was resolved, but it seems to still be happening to select users. Any solutions and/or updates on resolving this issue?

Does anyone have any insight on the first two issues, or has anyone also experienced similar issues. If so, how did you go about resolving it?

Comment: For the first issue, could you please attach some code even though it sounds like a bug from Google? For the second one,  Google slowly syncs the update to its whole content distribution network, which can take many hours. So User A sees the new version instantly, but User B doesn't see it until tomorrow. It could be that they've messed with the registry or configured Chrome in some custom way. But there isn't even an option to disable extension auto-updates, so it should work seamlessly. See the link: http://socialfixer.com/blog/2012/12/11/why-wont-chrome-update-my-social-fixer-extension/